# Where does sonar store its code coverage results in Jenkins workspace?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, cloudbees

We have a Jenkins master hosted by Cloudbees and we are using Sonar-as-a-Service.

We have a regular maven project, and we are using the Sonar "Post Build Action" to successfully collect code coverage.  I see the code coverage % in Sonar.  Everything works fine.

My question is this: If I examine the Jenkins workspace of this project, I cannot find the code coverage results.  I thought it would be saved in an xml file somewhere in the target directory, but i do not see it.  Does sonar save the results in the Jenkins workspace somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonar uses Jacoco by default for test coverage, this one uses a binary file afaik